# Collectors.groupingBy (Function, Supplier, Collector) doesn't accept lambda / dosen't see streamed values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I tried to group values using streams and Collectors. 
I have list of String which I have to split.

My data:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("Key:1,2,3")
stringList.add("Key:5,6,7")
```

**Key** is a key in map and **1,2,3** are a values in map

First I have tried using simple `toMap`

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> outputKeyMap = stringList.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id.split(":")[0], 
          id-> Arrays.stream(id.split(":")[1].split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it dosen't work because it always create the same key. So I need to use `groupingBy` function.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> outputKeyMap = stringList.stream().collect(groupingBy(id -> id.toString().split(":")[0],
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(id-> Arrays.stream(id.toString().split(":")[1].split(","))
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet()))));
```

But in this solution compiler dosen't see values passed into lambda functions, and I don't why because `Function` is as first parameter, and also into `Collectors.mapping`. In this solution stream doesn't work.

```
Collectors.groupingBy (Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier,
                                  Supplier<M> mapFactory,
                                  Collector<? super T, A, D> downstream)
```

**Edit: why groupingBy function doesn't work**

I forgot to add Collectors.toSet() in Collectors.mapping as the second parameter. But then I receive Set in Set so it wasn't what am I looking for. There should be used flatMapping but it is in Java9.

```
    Map<String, Set<Set<String>>> collect = stringList.stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(id -> id.split(":")[0],
                    TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(id-> Arrays.stream(id.toString().split(":")[1].split(","), 
                    Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: *'It dosen't work because it always create the same key'* -- naturally isn't it? Do you know how a *Map* works?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a map.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What's the type of the result Map? Is it `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, List<String>>` or `Map<String, List<Integer>>`? Please clarify and also provide expected output.

Comment: @NicholasK I think I know now. So know I used _groupingBy_. @YCF_L @Federico Peralta Schaffner Expected output is `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Comment: You will end up with a map of key 'Key' and value as '5,6,7' because as stated above a map can't have duplicate keys. This isn't an issue with *streams* but a mis-understanding of how a *Map* works.

Comment: @NicholasK I wrote that I figure it out. It was my first try then I use _groupingBy_ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the overload of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that accepts a *merge function*:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> result = stringList.stream()
        .map(string -> string.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 splitted -> splitted[0],
                 splitted -> Arrays.stream(splitted[1].split(","))
                                   .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)),
                 (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; }));
```

Here `(l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; }` is the merge function. It will be called by the collector whenever there's a key collision. As `List.addAll` mutates the list, we need to make sure that the first list that is created is mutable, hence the usage of `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))` in the value mapper function.

I've also optimized the first splitting to a `Stream.map` operation that is called before collecting, thus avoiding splitting more than once.

---

The above solution doesn't remove duplicates from the lists. If you need that, you should collect to a `Set` instead:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = stringList.stream()
        .map(string -> string.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 splitted -> splitted[0],
                 splitted -> Arrays.stream(splitted[1].split(","))
                                   .map(Integer::valueOf)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)),
                 (s1, s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s1; }));
```

Note that `LinkedHashSet` preserves insertion order.

Comment: `List::addAll` won't really work, a custom implementation like `(aList, bList) -> { 
                    aList.addAll(bList);
                    return aList;
                }` should do though.

Comment: Ok your solution works well but can any one explain me why lambda in my solution with grouping by doesn't work?

Comment: @Adriano It doesn't work due to a few reasons... 1. You're not passing a `Supplier`, but a `TreeMap` instead. Use `TreeMap::new` instead of `new TreeMap<>()` to fix it. You aren't converting the string to numbers either, and you're not splitting by comma, so you'll end up with lists of strings, where each string has the form `1,2,3` etc. `Collectors.groupingBy` is not the right tool for your requirement, because it doesn't let you handle key collisions easily. (It handles collisions on its own, by grouping to lists.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Ok I change it. It still doesn't work. Can you look up?

Comment: @Adriano The thing is that your solution collects to a map of lists of sets, i.e. to a `Map<String, List<Set<Integer>>> outputKeyMap`. Try changing the type of the map to that and see what happens. That `List<Set<Integer>>` in the values is why `groupingBy` is not the right solution here. You need to flatmap the comma-separated values somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have duplicate keys in your source list, you can get `Map<String, List<Integer>>` like:

```
 Map<String, List<Integer>> result = stringList.stream()
            .collect(toMap(string -> string.split(":")[0],
                    string -> Arrays.stream(string.split(":")[1].split(","))
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(toList())));
```

If you have duplicate keys, there is a way with `flatMapping` from java9:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> result = stringList.stream()
           .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.split(":")[0], 
                        flatMapping(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(":")[1].split(","))
                                           .map(Integer::valueOf), 
                        toList())));
```

The output will contain all integer values for `Key` :

`{Key=[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]}`

Comment: Assuming if I don't have duplicate keys. But I have it, so I need to use _groupingBy_ function instead of _toMap_

Comment: ...and `flatMapping` is Java-9

Comment: @nullpointer mm, you're right.. have not notice the `java-8` tag. Added info about java9 to the answer